# If I switch to another user, I can still see in the app the info from the last user, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am using Mongo in my app, I have a db named `test`, what I am doing now is just an app to understand the workflow among Angular, Nodejs and Mongo.

The issue I have right now, or actually I don't know if this an issue but, I created an user with the name of `User1` and a given email address, then I went to the app and saved some stuff, I logged out and then logged in again to confirm that the info I saved was there, and YES! the info was there it doesn't matter how many times and logged in and logged out.

Then I created another user with the name of `User2` and obviously a different email address, but when I logged in, the information I had save from `User1` was there.

I am on a local environment:

> Node version: 5.0.0
>
> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0

this is what I have regarding the user schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
  password: String,
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    email: String
  },
  google: {
    id: String,
    email: String
  }
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

mongoose.connect('localhost');
```

and here in Nodejs the signup route

```
app.post('/auth/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
});
```

and the service un Angular

```
  signup: function(user) {
    return $http.post('/auth/signup', user)
      .success(function() {
        $location.path('/login');            
      });
  }
```

the signup controller

```
.controller('SignupCtrl', function($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.signup = function() {
      Auth.signup({
        name: $scope.displayName,
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      });
    };
```

Here is the logging part:

Node:

```
app.post('/auth/login', function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) return res.status(401).send('User does not exist');
    user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (!isMatch) return res.status(401).send('Invalid email and/or password');
      var token = createJwtToken(user);
      res.send({ token: token });
    });
  });
});
```

Angular Service

```
  login: function(user) {
    return $http.post('/auth/login', user).success(function(data) {
        $window.localStorage.token = data.token;
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(data.token.split('.')[1]));
        $rootScope.currentUser = payload.user;
        $location.path('/');
      })
  }
```

Controller

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.login = function() {
      Auth.login({ email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password });
    };
```

**Update**

```
var tokenSecret = 'whatever goes here';

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    try {
      var decoded = jwt.decode(token, tokenSecret);
      if (decoded.exp <= Date.now()) {
        res.status(400).send('Access token has expired');
      } else {
        req.user = decoded.user;
        return next();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send('Error parsing token');
    }
  } else {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
}

function createJwtToken(user) {
  var payload = {
    user: user,
    iat: new Date().getTime(),
    exp: moment().add(7, 'days').valueOf()
  };
  return jwt.encode(payload, tokenSecret);
}
```

**[I created this Gist with the full code](https://gist.github.com/maketroli/e9fb2af33bc837a92f3960c9dfe3baa5)**

**[Here is the Github repository with all of the info](http://github.com/maketroli/trackIt)**

what do you think its happening?

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to populate the form etc when your user is logged in. Sounds like you're not passing the user id or it's not being used properly when storing/fetching data.

Comment: @Gavin see the code I added *Here is the logging part:*

Comment: Thanks @TheUnnamed - Could you possibly show the server side code for once you're logged in and it gets/stores the current user's information. I can see you're authenticating and generating a token, but we need to see how that token is used to convert back to the user id.

Comment: @Gavin see **Update** part, please. And thanks.

Comment: Thanks @TheUnnamed - Asides from how the token/current user is stored in Angular, everything looks ok so far. When you're expecting to see User2's information, can you show the code that gets this info from the server and any code you use (other than the registration code we already have) to update the user's information? Ideally we need as much information as possible as it's not possible to understand from what we have so far :(

Comment: @Gavin [Take a look at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/maketroli/e9fb2af33bc837a92f3960c9dfe3baa5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111783/discussion-between-gavin-and-theunnamed).

Comment: @Gavin see the chat, please.